# Regex para direciones IP de un CVS

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo un archivo csv con direcciones ip que necesito tratar necesito quitar una dirección IP el archivo es el siguiente:

Archivo.csv

```
10.87.28.70, 10.10.100.47, 10001
10.87.28.70, 10.10.100.47, 10002
10.87.28.70, 10.10.100.47, 10004
10.87.28.70, 10.10.100.47, 10005
10.87.28.70, 10.10.100.47, 10006
10.87.28.70, 10.10.100.47, 10007
10.12.35.111 10.12.35.122 10.10.35.166 10.12.35.187 10.10.35.194 10.10.35.19 10.12.35.21 10.12.3.231 10.10.35.39 10.12.35.49 **10.87.28.70,** 10.16.70.5, 8080(ESTA)
10.87.28.70, 10.10.100.47, 10005
10.87.28.70, 10.10.100.47, 10006
10.87.28.70, 10.10.100.47, 10007
```

Necesito quitar la dirección "10.87.28.70, " que escanea todos los puertos. El patron seria 10.87.28.70, 10.10.100.47, 10007 ( la IP necesito quitar esta -> 10.87.28.70 coma espacio cualquier otra ip coma espacio y un puerto).

Lo intento hacer con grep -Pv "10.87.28.70, ". El PROBLEMA puntual radica en que me quita también las lineas donde esa IP esta por ejemplo la del puerto 8080 en archivo de arriba y esas si las necesito considerar.

Yo e intentado con otras expresiones por ejemplo grep -Pv "^10.87.28.70, $" entre otras pero no lo he conseguido me quita todas las coincidencias de 10.87.28.70,

La salida deberia de ser que solo me detecte cosas como esta 10.87.28.70, 10.10.100.47, 10005 y no patrones donde en la primera columna tenga mas ips y aparte la 10.87.28.70.

Comment: A mi con `grep -v "^10.87.28.70"` solo me deja la linea que arranca con la `x.x.x.111`. Y me dio el mismo resultado en un mac (grep 2.5.1-FreeBSD) y en linux (GNU grep 3.7).

Comment: no bro es que asi me quitaria  cosas como (10.87.28.70 10.8.30.130 10.9.72.117 10.2.72.135 10.92.72.11 10.92.72.173 1.92.74.63 10.92.74.83 172.21.20.80, 10.11.0.124, 0 ) ya que encontrarian que tiene esa IP al inicio y esas si las necesito gracias por tu respuesta amigo de cualquier forma

Comment: Entiendo, esto me sirvió: `grep -v "^10.87.28.70,"`

Comment: mmm ¿podrías poner la salida exacta necesaria para el ejemplo que traes? Siempre es recomendado presentar un [mcve]